# What is the best solution to read external files (such like images) in Flink operators?

Tags: apache-flink

In some tasks, I may need to read the message from Kakfa. A message contains a path information of some files. I need to obtain further information from these files and output it to the subsequent operators of the pipeline. For example, each messag from Kafka contains a csv path. I need to first determine whether this csv exists, and then read certain columns from this csv and process it into an array.

A simple idea is that I use File.exists in FilterFunction to determine the existence, and then read and process files in RichMapFunction, but this does not seem to work.

I want to ask Flink supports external files inside the operator Does the system perform reading? Or I still need to try other ways (such as using a custom source, although I don't know how to use this way) to achieve my task.

Comment: When you tried to read and process files in a RichMapFunction, what did you try? That should be possible.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I access files through the java.io.File interface of Java. After careful inspection, I found that the real situation is: I have some images in path A. When I read images in the Flink pipeline, the error "javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!" will be triggered. But when I copy these images to path B, I can read these images normally in the Flink pipeline.Then I wrote a simple Java program using the same code to read images from path A, these images can also be read normally. So does Flink have any additional restrictions on the file system or path?

Comment: The files to be read must be in a filesystem accessible to every task manager in your cluster, and with permission to be read by the user that the task managers are running as.